# The images from Google Cloud bucket are not immediately updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, google-cloud-storage

When updating an image in Google Cloud bucket, even if the image update is successful, the url serves the old version for a while (few minutes, e.g. 5 min or so).

The link we are using looks like:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/path/to/images/1.jpg
```

The relevant part of the code which updates the image is:

```
var storageFile = bucket.file(imageToUpdatePath);
var storageFileStream = storageFile.createWriteStream({
  metadata: {
    contentType: req.file.mimetype
  }
});

storageFileStream.on('error', function(err) {
   ...
});

storageFileStream.on('finish', function() {
  // cloudFile.makePublic after the upload has finished, because otherwise the file is only accessible to the owner:
  storageFile.makePublic(function(err, data) {
    //if(err)
    //console.log(err);
    if (err) {
      return res.render("error", {
        err: err
      });
    }
    ...
  });
});
fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(storageFileStream);
```

It looks like a caching issue on the Google Cloud side. How to solve it? How to get the updated image at the requested url, after being updated?

In the Google Cloud admin, the new image *does* appear correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, public objects get cached for up to 60 minutes - see [Cache Control and Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#cache-control).  To fix this, you should set the cache-control property of the object to private when you create/upload the object.  In your code above, this would go in the `metadata` block, like so:

```
var storageFileStream = storageFile.createWriteStream({
  metadata: {
    contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    cacheControl: 'private'
  }
});
```

Comment: That fixed it indeed! Thank you so much. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples_1

```
    1. await bucket
                .file(filePath)
                .delete({ ignoreNotFound: true });

    // Deleting file with a name.
    
    const blob = bucket.file(filePath);
    
   2. await blob.save(fil?.buffer);

    //Saving File with the same name 
    
   3. const [metadata] = await storage
              .bucket(bucketName)
              .file(filePath)
              .getMetadata();
    
    newDocObj.location = metadata.mediaLink;

I have used metadata.mediaLink to get the 
latest download link of the image from Google Bucket Storage.
```